# Removal feature of Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am building a shopping list with Jquery and having some issues with the remove feature.   Basically I am trying to "remove" an item when they click on the x.  The remove feature is not working....do you guys have any suggestions?   Here is the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
//assigning the click event to the buttom
$('#addButton').click(function(){

    var listItem = $('#listItem');
    $('#shoppingList ul').append('<li>' + listItem.val() + "   X   " + '</li>');
    listItem.val('').focus();

});


$('#shoppingList').on("click", "X", function () {

    $('this').parent().remove();
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X` is not a valid selector in jQuery. In your case, it's just a normal text.

So one solution is to wrap your `X` inside a `span`, for example:

```
$('#shoppingList ul').append('<li>' + listItem.val() + "   <span class='close'>X</span>   " + '</li>');
```

then you can target this `span` using:

```
$('#shoppingList').on("click", "#shoppingList ul li span.close", function () { 
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Also note that you don't need to wrap `this` inside `' '`, so you need to use `$(this)` instead of `$('this')`.

Comment: Felix, this was definitely the trick!  Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

instead of

```
$('this').parent().remove();
```

`'this'` is just a string, and [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is a keyword that, in event handlers, references the element the event fired from.

Comment: is this the only problem ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek Probably not, seeing the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

This selector is wrong.

```
$('#shoppingList').on("click", "X", function () { });
```

It doesn't use the inner text there, but a normal jQuery selector.